# Django doesn't reflect changes made through dbshell in admin panel

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I have a table with some entries and it is being shown perfectly in the admin panel too. 
Now, I entered into dbshell (sqlite3) and altered the table to add a column named `tempColumn`. 
When I viewed the `db.sqlite3` file in online sqlite3 viewer, it showed the updated table with the new column ie. `tempColumn`. 

But when I go to admin panel to view the table there, it doesn't show the updated table... I even tried running `makemigrations` and `migrate` commands, but it shows *no migrations to apply*. 
This might be because, when i run `makemigrations` cmd, it must be checking if my table in models.py has been changed or not, which would remain unchanged as i altered the table through dbshell terminal. 

 So is there a way to reflect the changes made through dbshell to be visible in admin panel without actually adding the field in table in models.py ?

Comment: can you show queries you made?

Comment: Is it column? If it is you didn't save it to `models.py` and are registering from `models.py` to admin so django can not know if there were changes in database columns. That's what I think the issue might be.

Comment: @Hisham___Pak: ALTER TABLE pred_journaltable ADD tempColumn VARCHAR; this is the query where pred_journaltable is the name of the table and tempColumn is the name of new column

Comment: but the db.sqlite3 file was updated, so django won't know that a new column has been added even if i dont update `models.py`?

Comment: simply add `temp_column = models.CharField(max_length=200)` to `pred_journaltable` class in `models.py`, and then run `python manage.py makemigrations` and then `python  manage.py migrate`

Comment: yes neither can you make query outside admin.

Comment: Actually I was trying this coz I wanted to add a feature where I could add fields to my table dynamically. If this would've worked then I would've used these queries in some function which would get triggered whenever I clicked a button to add a filed. So that I won't have to edit my model.py again and again... Is there any other way then??

Comment: then you might want to see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34907014/django-allow-user-to-add-fields-to-model. Learn to search yourself for the best resource first.